# Setting up test inputs in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I have some methods that would require to execute over a java class.

For example my method receives as argument a class file, something like:

```
Information info = grabInformation("class_to_execute");
```

This method would run the `"class_to_execute"`and capture its output. And I would like to later assert its output with a given expected value.

My question is: how could I set up eclipse so that my test cases would find the classes that it will execute? Is adding the classes to the build path enough? Are there some variables I could set?

I don't think the `CLASSPATH` has anything to do with it.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to elaborate on that.

Comment: Did you check your classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "class_to_execute" is in another project or JAR, then add it to your Build Path under Libraries.  Do you have any reason to believe that's not enough?  Build path == CLASSPATH for most purposes.

If you're having Build Path or CLASSPATH problems, it might be easier to debug if you do this:

```
Information info = grabInformation(class_to_execute.class);
```

If it can't find the class, then put your cursor on the error and type Control+1.  Eclipse might be able to help you fix the Build Path automatically.